# Is SSB formula in ANOVA to find variance between groups valid for non-normal data?

Tags: anova, variance

I have two groups of non -normally distributed data (count data), and would like to find the variance between the groups. Am I able to use the SSB formula for this? The paper I have got the data from has calculated the between groups standard deviation as sd(group 1- group2) but I'm not sure how valid this is.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the variance is the formula for the variance, regardless of what numbers you are taking the variance of.  The real question is whether you really want to find this - or whether you want something else. That would depend on why you are calculating the SSB.